# Python function doesn´t respond

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging, sorting

I´m new to python. I have these four functions which are related but the last doesn´t respond.

```
import ui as numpy


def simulate_prizedoor(nsim):
    sim=ui.random.choice(3,nsim)
    return sims

def simulate_guess(nsim):
        guesses=ui.random.choice(3,nsim)
        return guesses

def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):


        result = ui.random.randint(0, 3, prizedoors.size)
        while True:
            bad = (result == prizedoors) | (result == guesses)
            if not bad.any():
                return result
            result[bad] = ui.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())

def switch_guesses(guesses, goatdoors):


            result = ui.random.randint(0, 3, guesses.size)
            while True:
                bad = (result == guesses) | (result == goatdoors)
                if not bad.any():
                    return result
                result[bad] = ui.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())
```

As you see the third and the four function has the same code.

I run the first and the second function :

```
a=simulate_prizedoor(4)
b=simulate_guess(4)
print(a)
[2 2 0 2]
print (b)
[2 0 0 2]
```

Then, I run the third function with the values of a and b

```
c=goat_door(a,b)
print(c)
[1 1 2 1]
```

Finally, I run the last function but python didn´t respond, it´s seems that it´s a infinite process to give the answer.

```
   switch_guess(b,c)
```

Edit:

Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: It seems that, `def switch_guesses(guesses, goatdoors):` running endlessly, change your exit condition of `while` loop

Comment: Your code should give you NameErrors, because you're importing ui as numpy but then you're using ui in the code.

Comment: yes, please post your actual code instead of re-writing it...

Comment: I´ve edited, is ui. My actul code is in the post.

Comment: I highly doubt that, at least your first line is wrong. what is the module ui you're importing as numpy?

Comment: I started with python 1 week ago, as far as know, ui as numpy, gives the entire library for arrays. I use Ipython 2.7 from Anaconda.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood something. Importing another module as `numpy` doesn't magically make it the `numpy` module. You'd normally do `import numpy` instead, provided you have it installed.

Comment: The rest of your code still refers to `ui`, but you have no global name `ui` in your module. You bound the `ui` module to the name `numpy` instead. None of your code will work, but instead throw `NameError`s.

Comment: I have installed numpy, otherwise the other functions wouldn´t have run. I use Ipython 2.7 from Ananconda which comes with a range of packages such as numpy, pandas, etc.

Comment: Looks like this is the original question http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/cs109/content/blob/master/HW0.ipynb

Comment: Yes, the problem is that my fourth function doesn´t respond and it has the same code as my third function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted has errors that prevent it from running. Please post the original unmodified code when asking a question - you will be much more likely to get constructive feedback and good answers.

Here are the errors I found with the code you posted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "montyhall.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ui as numpy
ImportError: No module named ui
```

My guess at correct line: `import numpy as ui`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "montyhall.py", line 27, in <module>
    a=simulate_prizedoor(4)
  File "montyhall.py", line 5, in simulate_prizedoor
    return sims
NameError: global name 'sims' is not defined
```

My guess at correct function:

```
def simulate_prizedoor(nsim):
    sim=ui.random.choice(3,nsim)
    return sim
```

Your indenting is also a bit strange.

---

The corrected code I ran is included below. When I run it, there are no errors and the `simulate_prizedoor` function does not get stuck in a loop. Perhaps the code you are running has differences that are causing the problem?

```
import numpy as ui

def simulate_prizedoor(nsim):
    sim=ui.random.choice(3,nsim)
    return sim

def simulate_guess(nsim):
    guesses=ui.random.choice(3,nsim)
    return guesses

def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):
    result = ui.random.randint(0, 3, prizedoors.size)
    while True:
        bad = (result == prizedoors) | (result == guesses)
        if not bad.any():
            return result
        result[bad] = ui.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())

def switch_guesses(guesses, goatdoors):
    result = ui.random.randint(0, 3, guesses.size)
    while True:
        bad = (result == guesses) | (result == goatdoors)
        if not bad.any():
            return result
        result[bad] = ui.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())

a=simulate_prizedoor(4)
b=simulate_guess(4)
print(a)
print (b)
c=goat_door(a,b)
print(c)
d=switch_guesses(b,c)
print(d)
```

Comment: The only error in my post is to write import ui as numpy intead of import numpy as ui. Then, my code is the same that I've posted in the forum and it´s still stack in a loop.

Comment: @CreamStat even the screenshot has different code to what you posted - it has no return statement. This is probably why it doesn't return. This is why it's important to copy/paste the exact code you're running.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen that I forgot to write return result in my code. How bad is my sight!. Thanks for your help and I promise to be more careful!